# can I use Anova test to analyse this table

Tags: anova

can I use ANOVA to compare number of days of asthma attacks per month followed for six months between two groups (group 1 and group 2). so we have a 2x6 table in rows we have the months (1st, 2nd, 3rd, .....sixth) and in column there are the groups (group 1 and group 2). each cell contain the total number of attacks of asthma per month (please see the attached table
[image: table]

Comment: One problem is that the assumption of independence would not seem to be tenable. Secondly "days of asthma attacks" sounds like counts (each member of each group presumably having a 0/1 outcome on each day), which implies equality of variance is unlikely and by the look og it, you also have a problem with 0's (Red Zone/AAIG), so I don't think you can treat it as homoskedastic or normally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @glenb 's excellent comments:

1) Independence: It seems like you have the same people measured over multiple months. That would violate independence because the number of attacks that a person has in month 2 is related to the number he/she had in month 1.

2) Number of attacks is a count.  You can't have 1/2 an attack or negative attacks.  This isn't much of an issue when the number of attacks is large and varied, but it's a problem for the red zone.

3) 0's.  Glen is right again that you  have a problem here.

So, my answer is "no" and my suggestion is that you should probably use a nonlinear multilevel model with a zero inflated link (either Poisson or negative binomial).

Comment: thanks so much for your  insight answer. could you please tell me how can  I use a nonlinear multilevel model with a zero inflated link (either Poisson or negative binomial). to test the difference between the two study groups over the six months?

Comment: You would need a course or an entire text to learn those.