# Can I do ANOVA?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to do ANOVA in SPSS. I have data from 3 time-points and 3 groups. But the problem is I have only one value for each category. How can I see the significant difference between the groups in this case?

I will attach a model sample data with this:

[image]

I would like to compare if there is any significant difference between the value for each group under different time period. Please help me in this regard. Thank you

Comment: See if this helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191927/can-i-use-anova-test-to-analyse-this-table?rq=1

Comment: the values under t1, t2 and t3 are independent. it is the number of working days in a year